# Maui Platform namespace is not recognised

Tags: maui, maui-windows, maui-android

I am implementing a project in my Maui app to display a pointer over buttons and links on Windows. ([vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Setting-a-cursor-for-.NET-MAUI-VisualElement/](https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Setting-a-cursor-for-.NET-MAUI-VisualElement/))

At the class CursorBehavior I need to import the platform -namespaces to use the method SetCustomCursor(..). Visual Studio knows, which namespaces are missing.
[image]

After the (automatic) import of the namespaces, however, they are marked as faulty (on Android, MacCatalyst, Windows).
[image]

Only for iOS the message is different:
[image]

I tried also to set them all as global usings, what makes no differences.

Here as example the class CursorExtensions at Platforms.Android:
[image]

**How can I use the platform namespaces?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't add all the platforms namespace in the share project directly. You can only add one of them which depends on the target platform.

[image: Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions]

Such as the picture shows, you can just add the Platforms.Android namespace.

In addition, I checked the link you provided. You don't have to add all the platforms namespace. You can check the [author's source code on the github](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/blob/main/MauiCursor/CursorBehavior.cs).

Comment: Yes, at CursorBehavior classes at the platforms the namespace must be only the project name without .Platforms.OperatingSystem! Thats the solution. Thank you!

Comment: This helped - instead of MyApp.Platforms.Android.Services, I just add my conditional services to the MyApp.Services namespace.  Additionally, ALL platforms need to have a file in MyApp.Services to avoid an error from that specific project about the namespace being found.  In my case, since I wasn't targeting Mac/Windows/Tizen, I had to delete those folders and remove all references to Mac/Windows/Tizen in the project file to get my project to build with a service that had a different implementation for iOS and Android.